# Order Summary is not Showing on pull Down

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, checkout-page, order-summary

Order Summary is not showing any information on pulldown. All of a sudden it stopped working. Any ideas why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest below steps to identify the issue and based that we can solve it.

1. Check the console log and see if we are getting any error
2. If any JS error is there then we need to fix it.
3. No console error, then we need to change the third party theme to luma defualt magento theme.
4. Still issue is there then it seems, it is related to third-party extensions. So try to disable extension one by one and see where is the issue.
5. Don't forget to run Magento upgrade and static-content command before checking steps #3 and #4.

I hope this will help you. Or let me know if you get the issue.